# Favorite button Android in Shared Preference

Tags: java, android, favorites

i'm making a recipe application and would like to create a favourite button where the user will click on the grey star button and it will change into a yellow star button(i have a picture of a grey star and a yellow star), the selected favourites will then display in a list once you click on the favourites link on the home screen

I have the following code in a layout

```
 <ImageButton android:id="@+id/favouritebtn"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:src="@drawable/staroff"
      android:background="#00ffffff"
      android:onClick="onToggleStar"
      android:clickable="true"/>
```

Can anyone help me in how to write the code so that when i click on the star it will turn yellow and add to the favourite list

**UPDATE**

FavouriteBtn.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class FavouriteBtn extends Activity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.recipe);

    final ImageButton imgButton =(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.favbtn);
    imgButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            boolean isFavourite = readState();

            if (isFavourite) {
                imgButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.staroff);
                isFavourite = false;
                saveState(isFavourite);

            } else {
                imgButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.staron);
                isFavourite = true;
                saveState(isFavourite);

            }

        }
    });

}

private void saveState(boolean isFavourite) {
    SharedPreferences aSharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences(
            "Favourite", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor aSharedPreferencesEdit = aSharedPreferences
            .edit();
    aSharedPreferencesEdit.putBoolean("State", isFavourite);
    aSharedPreferencesEdit.commit();
}

private boolean readState() {
    SharedPreferences aSharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences(
            "Favourite", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return aSharedPreferences.getBoolean("State", true);
}

}
```

recipe.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/jbsbackground2"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_detail"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/barbecuedporkribs" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="10dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/iv_detail"
    android:background="#3D3C3A" />

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/iv_detail"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="Recipe"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/favourites"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textStyle="italic" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvFavourite"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Add To Favourites (click star)"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_above="@+id/tvName"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/favbtn"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:src="@drawable/staroff"
            android:background="#00ffffff"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:clickable="true"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvTD"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Ingredients"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvIngredients"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvTD"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textStyle="italic" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvK"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvIngredients"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="Preparation"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvPreparation"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvK"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textStyle="italic" />
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?  If you search for how to tell when a user clicks on a button and how to change an image you should find some very simple answers.

Comment: OP, use android rating bar example here - http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-rating-bar-example/ and convert it to your needs (In your case, Favourites)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use ToggleButton in your XML:

```
<ToggleButton
    android:layout_width="180dp"
    android:layout_height="180dp"
    android:id="@+id/myToggleButton"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:textOn=""
    android:textOff=""/>
```

And in your Activity:

```
ToggleButton toggleButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    toggleButton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.myToggleButton);
    toggleButton.setChecked(false);
    toggleButton.setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.img_star_grey));
    toggleButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked)
                toggleButton.setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(),R.drawable.img_star_yellow));
            else
                toggleButton.setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.img_star_grey));
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, when I use this code i was getting an error on getDrawable about the API level 21 and the current min was 8, so i added getResource(). in front of each getDrawable but now the app crashes, do you know how to fix this

Comment: @john Yes. I updated my answer.

Comment: Hey thanks for getting back to me, I changed the code around to how you updated your answer but now the app crashes when I click on the recipe TextView to open the list of recipes i get the following error message "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ToggleButton.setChecked(boolean)' on a null object reference" i will add the MainActivity.java to my question for a better look at the whole code

Comment: @john Yes your app crashes because it looks like you did not add the ToggleButton in your xml layout. findViewById(R.id.myToggleButton) returns null becuse it isn't there.

Comment: I have added the ToggleButton to my xml layout though, i copied and pasted the code you have above but it doesn't seem to stop it crashing :-\

Comment: @john Ok. Show the xml, please :)

Comment: updated the xml to the question :)

Comment: @john replace setContentView(R.layout.main) with setContentView(R.layout.recipe)

Answer (score 4):

use the code for change Background Button
also you can save state button in SharedPreferences

```
    favouritebtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            boolean isFavourite = readStae();

            if (isFavourite) {
                favouritebtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.imgStarGrey);
                isFavourite = false;
                saveStae(isFavourite);

            } else {
                favouritebtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.imgStaryellow);
                isFavourite = true;
                saveStae(isFavourite);

            }

        }
    });
```

also add the Method

```
  private void saveStae(boolean isFavourite) {
    SharedPreferences aSharedPreferenes = this.getSharedPreferences(
            "Favourite", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor aSharedPreferenesEdit = aSharedPreferenes
            .edit();
    aSharedPreferenesEdit.putBoolean("State", isFavourite);
    aSharedPreferenesEdit.commit();
}

private boolean readStae() {
    SharedPreferences aSharedPreferenes = this.getSharedPreferences(
            "Favourite", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return aSharedPreferenes.getBoolean("State", true);
}
```

Comment: Hi, whenevever i use your code i get the following error "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method onClick(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.widget.ImageButton with id 'favbtn'" I've updated my question and added my java and xml file, if you could take a look and tell me where I've gone wrong please