# how to save this icon once clicked?

Tags: android, click, switch-statement

Once run and click on the icon `heart_red` changed back to `heart_grey` after exiting the application

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.menu_favorites:
            if(!item.isChecked()) {
                item.setChecked(true);
                item.setIcon(R.drawable.heart_red);                    
                return true;
            }else{
                item.setChecked(false);
                item.setIcon(R.drawable.heart_grey);


                return true;

            }
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);


}
```

Comment: for what you want to save state i think you are doing code of like button right

Comment: I want to make a favorite icon, iam newbie, please help me?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34980309/favourite-button-android

Comment: Thank you for helping, but this can not be

Comment: from what you are showing data?? is that local DB or json file or from server

Comment: class above where I display data only from TextView and string